# Unable to modernize these C-style casts

Tags: visual-c++, casting

Code:

```
int CChristianLifeMinistryEditorDlg::CompareDate(const void* pArg1, const void* pArg2)
{
    const STUDENT_ASSIGN_HIST_S* psAssign1 = *((STUDENT_ASSIGN_HIST_S * *)pArg1);
    const STUDENT_ASSIGN_HIST_S* psAssign2 = *((STUDENT_ASSIGN_HIST_S * *)pArg2);
    int                 iGreater = 0; // assume they are the same

    if (psAssign1->datMeeting < psAssign2->datMeeting)
        iGreater = -1;
    else if (psAssign1->datMeeting > psAssign2->datMeeting)
        iGreater = 1;

    return iGreater;
}
```

I am struggling to work out how to modernize the C-style casts:

```
const STUDENT_ASSIGN_HIST_S* psAssign1 = *((STUDENT_ASSIGN_HIST_S * *)pArg1);
const STUDENT_ASSIGN_HIST_S* psAssign2 = *((STUDENT_ASSIGN_HIST_S * *)pArg2);
```

I tried:

```
const STUDENT_ASSIGN_HIST_S* psAssign1 = *(static_cast<STUDENT_ASSIGN_HIST_S * *>(pArg1));
const STUDENT_ASSIGN_HIST_S* psAssign1 = *(reinterpret_cast<STUDENT_ASSIGN_HIST_S * *>(pArg1));
```

And it both instances VS told me it was an invalid cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
typedef const STUDENT_ASSIGN_HIST_S* PCSAHS;

//...

PCSAHS psAssign1 = *(static_cast<const PCSAHS*>(pArg1));
```

`pArg1` has `const` qualifier, so it needs to be preserved when casting.

Comment: That appears to work fine - thanks! I added the `typedef` inside the function itself. I assume that was OK? I got no warnings.

Comment: So `PCSAHS*` becomes `STUDENT_ASSIGN_HIST_S**` as in the original cast along with the `const`.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle, that is correct. The main reason to use `typedef` is to "break" the `**` pointer in two, but I think it also makes code a bit more concise. Obviously you can name it anyway you want.